# Problema con directiva en Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente código que tiene la directiva `<count-characteres>`

```
 <label class="control-label"><cr/>Género <count-characters c-name="genero"></count-characters></label>
        <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" name="genero" class="form-control" name="genero" equired="" ng-model="produccionGeneroSel.genero" ng-maxlength="{{validations.genero.maxlength}}">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-font"></i></span>
        </div>
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que cuando se comience a escribir en el `input` empiece un contador de caracteres restantes y cuando salgo del `input` que desaparezca y no estoy pudiendo llamar a la `directiva`, pasando el `maxlength` y que sepa en que `input` estoy escribiendo. Intente con `$watch` pero no pude hacer andar

```
app.directive('countCharacters', ['$injector', function ($injector) {
        return{
            retric:'E',
            replace: true,
            scope:{
                cName: '=name'
            },
            template: function(){
                return '<span>caracteres restantes</span>';  },

            link: function($scope, element, $attrs){


            }
        };

    }]);
```

pienso usarlo por la etiqueta `name` del `input` por si hay varios en un mismo formulario.

Comment: Pero no necesitas crear una directiva para mostrar los carácteres restantes en un input.. eso se puede realizar con un poco de lógica y aplicando `ng-init` =/

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera estoy utilizando hace poco angular, me podrias ejemplificar lo que decis por favor? este es el escenario. Yo tengo muchos formularios y algunos tienen 5,6,7 inputs, y tendria que contar caracteres de cada uno por eso pensaba en una directiva para poner al lado de cada input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es agregar un contador a cada input, entonces inténtalo utilizando [`ng-transclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) en la directiva.

En escencia lo que hace es que pinta el contenido dentro de la directiva como si perteneciera al template de la directiva. Entonces en el metodo `link` haces la lógica para contar la cantidad de caracteres en el input y mostrarlo:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive("countCharacter",function(){
  return {
    restrict:"E",
    transclude:true,
    template: "<div><span ng-transclude></span> <span><span class='counter-container'> <span class='counter' /> caracteres restantes</span></div>",
    link : function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
 
  var input = $element.find("input");
  var max = parseInt(input.attr("maxlength"));
  
  var counterSpanContainer = input.parent().parent().find(".counter-container").hide();
   var counterSpan = counterSpanContainer.find(".counter");
   
    counterSpan.text(max);
   
  input.focusin(function(){
   counterSpanContainer.show();
  })
  .focusout(function(){
   counterSpanContainer.hide();
  }).on('keyup',function(){
   counterSpan.text(max - this.value.length);
  });
    }
  }
})
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

   <count-character>
     Contador 1
     <input type="text" maxlength="10" ng-model="texto" />
   </count-character>

   <count-character>
     Contador 2
     <input type="text" maxlength="5" ng-model="texto" />
   </count-character>
 
</div>
```

En este ejemplo, todo lo que esta dentro de la directiva `<count-character>` se pintara dentro del span `<span ng-transclude></span>`, entonces a eso le agregamos otro span que sera el contador de caracteres. Luego en la funcion link, obtenemos el input y le agregamos un evento `keyup` para así por cada letra que se escriba, actualizamos el contador.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que necesitas se puede realizar con **[ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)**, **[ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)** y **[ng-focus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus)** de la siguiente manera:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.mensaje = 'Bienvenido!';
  $scope.focus = true;
  
  $scope.updateBlur = function(){
    $scope.focus = false;
  }
  
  $scope.updateFocus = function(){
    $scope.focus = true;
  }
}])
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-cloak>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-blur="updateBlur()" ng-focus="updateFocus()" ng-init="characteres = 20" ng-model="mensaje" maxlength="20"> 
  <p ng-show="focus">{{characteres - mensaje.length}} caracteres restantes</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

> - **ng-init** sirve para crear una variable y darle algún valor inicial.
> - **ng-blur** es una directiva nativa de AngularJS que maneja el evento de un elemento cuando éste pierde el foco
> - **ng-focus** es lo contrario a ng-blur.

Nos comentas como te va!

Comment: Gracias me sirvio. solo que falla cuando agregas otro input, pero calculo que con algun atributo extra funcionaria

Comment: El problema puede ser que estás utilizando la misma variable para todos los input (`$scope.focus`).. tendrás que invocar un poco de creatividad para resolver eso colega =)